# Elegant way to abstract index traversal

Tags: c#, linq

I have two methods that do the exact same thing, except one examines a range of indices going forward from Current, and the other examines a range going backward from Current. I have abstracted the functionality so that the common code is in one method and it just takes an IEnumerable as a parameter to know the range of indices to iterate through. So now my two methods are simplified to:

```
private List<Thingy> GetForwardThingies()
{
    var indices = new List<int>();
    for (var i = _project.Current; i < _project.GetLimit(); i++)
        indices.Add(i);
    return GetThingiesByIteratingOverIndices(indices);
}

private List<Thingy> GetBackwardsThingies()
{
    var indices = new List<int>();
    for (var i = _project.Current; i >= 0; i--)
        indices.Add(i);
    return GetThingiesByIteratingOverIndices(indices);
}
```

Is there a more elegant way (perhaps using LINQ) to encapsulate this abstraction? GetThingiesByIteratingOverIndices is pretty fast and not speed-critical, as it will be operating over no more than a few dozen indices, so efficiency is not a primary concern. I was thinking maybe the new System.Range thing in C# 8.0 would help, but alas it does not allow a way to express a backwards range. (And, yes, order is important, so I can't go from 0 to Current to get the Backwards Thingies.)

### New information

Okay, I was trying to keep it simple, but I guess I need to give the real implementation of **GetThingiesByIteratingOverIndices**:

```
private List<ScriptLine> GetRecordableBlocksUpThroughHole(IEnumerable<int> indices)
{
    var bookInfo = _project.SelectedBook;
    var chapter = _project.SelectedChapterInfo.ChapterNumber1Based;
    var lines = new List<ScriptLine>();
    foreach (var i in indices)
    {
        if (!_project.IsLineCurrentlyRecordable(bookInfo.BookNumber, chapter, i))
            break;
        var block = bookInfo.ScriptProvider.GetBlock(bookInfo.BookNumber, chapter, i);
        lines.Add(block);
        if (!block.Skipped && !ClipRepository.GetHaveClip(_project.Name, bookInfo.Name, chapter, i, _project.ScriptProvider))
            return lines;
    }
    return new List<ScriptLine>();
}
```

Comment: `[0..MaxValue].Reverse()` ?

Comment: I'd tempted to mark that as the answer (if it weren't a comment) since it appears elegant. However, since the new System.Index and System.Range types are not (and apparently will not be) included in .net Framework, the new range syntax isn't even available to me. Perhaps others who come her and are targeting .net Core 3.0 will find this useful.

Answer (score 3):

```
private List<Thingy> GetForwardThingies() =>
    _whateverEnumerableYouAreIterating.Skip(_project.Current)
                                      .ToList();

private List<Thingy> GetBackwardsThingies() =>
    _whateverEnumerableYouAreIterating.Take(_project.Current - 1)
                                      .Reverse()
                                      .ToList();
```

Of course iterating eagerly (`.ToList()`) is alltogether optional; you can always return an `IEnumerable<Thingy>` and defer execution to whenever the caller decides to.

Your code is probably more efficient in both cases (`Skip` and `Reverse` can be somewhat expensive), but if the number of iterated items is small it wont be that much of an issue as you correctly assume in your question.

Comment: There is no single object that encapsulates the things I'm enumerating. (I almost stated that in my original description - I guess I should have.) That is why I'm passing an IEnumerable<int>. GetThingiesByIteratingOverIndices uses each index multiple times to access various supporting methods that retrieve state information.

Comment: @TomBogle Ok, thats relevant information. Still, you can apply the same solution to retrieve the indices and then, either use the resulting enumerations the same way you do now, or use a projection `.Select(i => GetThingyByIndex(i))` if such method were available.

Comment: I've added "New Information" above that I think illustrates why a simple projection won't work.